# Modificar dictionary

Tags: vb.net

¿Alguien me podría enseñar cómo modificar las propiedades de un objeto mientras voy recorriendo el dictionary? Por ejemplo, cuando llegue al `key 2` o `dia 2`, necesito modificar la propiedad `dinero`.

```
Dim persona1 As New Persona
persona1.Dia = 1
persona1.Dinero = 200

Dim persona2 As New Persona
persona2.Dia = 2
persona2.Dinero = 0

Dim persona3 As New Persona
persona3.Dia = 3
persona3.Dinero = 300

Dim persona4 As New Persona
persona4.Dia = 4
persona4.Dinero = 500

Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Persona)
dictionary.Add(1, persona1)
dictionary.Add(2, persona2)
dictionary.Add(3, persona3)
dictionary.Add(4, persona4)

Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Persona)
For Each pair In dictionary
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No veo la complicación. Simplemente le agregas una condición dentro del `For Each`.

Por ejemplo, si lo quieres hacer por `Key = 2`:

```
For Each pair In dictionary
    If pair.Key = 2 Then
        pair.Value.Dinero = 1000
    End If
Next
```

O si lo quieres hacer por `Dia = 2`:

```
For Each pair In dictionary
    If pair.Value.Dia = 2 Then
        pair.Value.Dinero = 1000
    End If
Next
```

Pero lo mejor es no recorrer el `dictionary` usando un bucle. Puedes acceder al `Key = 2` directamente de esta manera:

```
dictionary(2).Dinero = 1000
```